# Joomla Advertisement issue

Tags: joomla

I am using Joomla 3.0.I want to show banners on the basis of articles.

I really wants that admin can add banner for an particular article and will show on front on that article.

Please suggest me any plugin

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a 3rd party solution for that.
You could use the default banner module:

```
Extensions -> Module Manager -> New -> Banners
```

And import it to article using loadmodule method: [How do you put a module inside an article?](http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_put_a_module_inside_an_article%3F)

```
{loadmodule mod_banners, banner1}
```

* banner1 is the title of module

Comment: I think its not the best solution ,Because for example if i  have 30 articles ,so i have to create  30 modules.Any other solution

Comment: That's the easiest solution. If you want to try something else, you have to search for a [banner management](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/ads-a-affiliates/banner-management) component.